# Same face within headline after new line in org mode

Tags: org-mode, faces

A new line within a headline currently results in a different (the default, I guess) face. (Different from the beginning of the headline, I mean.) How can I make the entire headline face the same?

MWE

```
* I'd like this,
to be the same face as this.
* Thanks!
```

Screenshot of what that looks like on my machine:
[image]

Also (and better!) I'd like to know how I could figure this out myself. E.g. where in the manual would I look. (I couldn't find anything in the org mode manual.)

Comment: You cannot have a newline in a headline. The newline puts the next line into the body of the outline node.

Comment: BTW, that is inherited from Org mode's parent mode: `outline-mode`. You can see that by `C-h f org-mode RET` and reading the doc string. So in addition to the Org mode docs, you should consult the `Outline mode` section of the Emacs manual: `C-h i g (emacs) Outline mode RET`.

Comment: Thanks @NickD. I'm gonna investigate what you guys have said. Side question: Am I using the term "face" correctly?

Comment: I think so: at least, both @db48x and I understood what you meant. For more info, see the "Text Faces" section in the Emacs manual, which you can get to from within Emacs with `C-h i g (emacs) Faces`. Eventually, you might want to read the Emacs Lisp Manual section on faces: `C-h i  g (elisp) Faces`.